# Turning 8 characters unix timestamp into datetime

Tags: mysql, unix-timestamp

I got a table which include event time as timestamp, but there are only 8 characters in it, for example

```
2015-04-01 as 22481616,
2015-04-02 as 22568016,
2015-04-03 as 22654416,
2015-05-02 as 25160017,
2014-12-01 as 12030816
```

I try to select hour and minute from unix timestamp but i can't. any idea?

Comment: What is the data type of the field containing the timestamp? Are the examples you're giving actual examples from your db? It doesn't seem to be a Unix timestamp since the highest Unix timestamp containing 8 digits (99999999) represents a date in 1973.

Comment: these are actual examples from db, data type of the field is int(11) unsigned

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you have there is not a unix timestamp. It's the number of seconds since `2014-07-14 19:06:24`.

So you can get your times with this query:

```
SELECT FROM_UNIXTIME(1405357584 + ...);
```

Example:

```
mysql> select from_unixtime(1405357584 + 22481616);
+--------------------------------------+
| from_unixtime(1405361184 + 22481616) |
+--------------------------------------+
| 2015-04-01 00:00:00                 |
+--------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: Thank you! I can find with this query only 1 hour difference, is it spesific issue or using seconds since 2014-07-14 19:06:24 is general usage?

Comment: Never heard of it. You can just add or substract 3600 to that number to adjust the hours. Check with `SELECT FROM_UNIXTIME(1405357584 + 60 * 60 + 22568016);` -> (`2015-04-01 01:00:00`).